# Subtracting columns of data frame by name

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

Let's assume I have a data frame as bellow:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1,20,1),nrow=4), byrow=TRUE)
colnames(df) <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")
rownames(df) <- as.Date(c("2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05"))

df
           X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
2020-01-02  1  2  3  4  5
2020-01-03  6  7  8  9 10
2020-01-04 11 12 13 14 15
2020-01-05 16 17 18 19 20
```

I want to subtract all columns from the first column `X1` and store it in the same column. I have tried doing

```
  for(i in colnames(df)){
    df[i] <- lapply(df[i], function(x) x-df["X1"])
  }
```

But it only applies it to the first column. How can I run it for all the columns?

Comment: This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995869/subtracting-columns-of-data-frame-by-name/63996085#comment113165355_63996056) of mine might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `base R` solution without loop. Just have in mind the position of columns:

```
#Data
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1,20,1),nrow=4), byrow=TRUE)
colnames(df) <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")
rownames(df) <- as.Date(c("2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05"))
#Set columns for difference
df[,2:5] <- df[,2:5]-df[,1]
```

Output:

```
           X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
2020-01-02  1  4  8 12 16
2020-01-03  2  4  8 12 16
2020-01-04  3  4  8 12 16
2020-01-05  4  4  8 12 16
```

Or a more sophisticated way would be:

```
#Create index
#Var to substract
i1 <- which(names(df)=='X1')
#Vars to be substracted with X1
i2 <- which(names(df)!='X1')
#Compute
df[,i2]<-df[,i2]-df[,i1]
```

Output:

```
           X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
2020-01-02  1  4  8 12 16
2020-01-03  2  4  8 12 16
2020-01-04  3  4  8 12 16
2020-01-05  4  4  8 12 16
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `lapply` you may do it like so:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, `-`, df$X1)
df
#            X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 2020-01-02  0  4  8 12 16
# 2020-01-03  0  4  8 12 16
# 2020-01-04  0  4  8 12 16
# 2020-01-05  0  4  8 12 16
```

Comment: `microbenchmark` says this is the fastest of all by a factor of 6. With bigger dataframes, the factor increases. With `nrow(df) == 65536` it goes up to 30 ([Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63995972/8245406)) or 45-50 ([mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996085/8245406)).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `grep`:

```
i_col <- grep("X1", names(df))
df[] <- df - df[, i_col]
df
#           X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#2020-01-02  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-03  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-04  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-05  0  4  8 12 16
```

And another, with `grep/sweep`. In fact, `-` is `sweep`'s default function.

```
sweep(df, 1, df[[i_col]], check.margin = FALSE)
#           X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#2020-01-02  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-03  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-04  0  4  8 12 16
#2020-01-05  0  4  8 12 16
```